# spring-core 3.2.9 + java 8

Tags: spring, java-8

We've upgraded our project using spring 3.2.9 to java 8. Once we start using java 8 features, spring will no longer start (see stack trace below).

I tried to exclude old usages of asm and include the following dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
    <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
    <artifactId>asm-util</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
    <artifactId>asm-commons</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

However, it does not solve the problem. Does anybody have an idea how to solve this?

Unfortunately, we cannot upgrade to spring 4 as we use some dependencies that would make this upgrade pretty time consuming.

```
Offending resource: class path resource [xxxx/context-test.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [xxxxx.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: INVOKESPECIAL/STATIC on interfaces require ASM 5
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:256)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:139)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:64)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [xxxxxxxxxxxxx.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: INVOKESPECIAL/STATIC on interfaces require ASM 5
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:290)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:242)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.parse(ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:73)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1438)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1428)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:139)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:250)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: INVOKESPECIAL/STATIC on interfaces require ASM 5
    at org.springframework.asm.MethodVisitor.visitMethodInsn(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.b(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:64)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:80)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:102)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:266)
    ... 58 more
```

Comment: I've posted an answer to a very similar question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30072135/spring-3-2-x-with-java-8/33936697#33936697 basically, the problem is not compiling in Java8 but using new java 8 syntax (such as :: or ->)

Answer (score 21):

You need to upgrade to a Spring 4.x version.

Spring 3.2.x will only support **Java 8 runtimes compiled against Java 7**. You cannot use "static interfaces" as that is a [Java 8 feature](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/enhancements.html#javase8) and will not compile against Java 7.

Here is a relevant snippet from some of the [Spring 4 release notes](http://spring.io/blog/2013/05/21/spring-framework-4-0-m1-3-2-3-available/), emphasis theirs:

> Along with 4.0 M1, we’ve released **Spring Framework 3.2.3**, containing
>   fixes for recently reported issues but also coming with OpenJDK 8
>   runtime support. Spring Framework 3.2.x will support **deployment on JDK
>   8 runtimes for applications compiled against JDK 7** (with -target 1.7)
>   or earlier.

And from their comments in the [build.gradle file for spring-framework](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/eef0bf43d5d2a8ad5d0799cd1dd33fd7d151ae1d/build.gradle#L270-L273), they repackage CGLib as part of their release and [embed ASM into the project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/tree/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/asm).

```
// As of Spring 4.0.3, spring-core includes asm 5.0 and repackages cglib 3.1, inlining
// both into the spring-core jar. cglib 3.1 itself depends on asm 4+, and is therefore
// further transformed by the JarJar task to depend on org.springframework.asm; this
// avoids including two different copies of asm unnecessarily.
```

Here is another relevant section from the 4.0.3 release notes that shows how they embed some of these libraries and what is supported in Spring 4.0.3.

> It's my pleasure to announce that Spring Framework 4.0.3 is available.
>   This is the first release of the framework after Java 8's launch last
>   week; it is built with OpenJDK 8 GA now and includes the latest ASM
>   5.0.1 (with bytecode support at the JDK 8 GA level as well, superseding the custom ASM 4.2 fork that we were previously using).

Comment: Could you please explain `Spring 3.2.x will only support Java 8 runtimes compiled against Java 7`? Would Spring 3.2.x be compatible if I have JDK 1.8 and JVM version 1.7?

Comment: @VaibhavAgarwal It means that your code should be compiled for Java 7 but can run on a Java 8 JVM. I.e. `javac -source 1.7 -target 1.7` code will run with a JVM version 1.8.

Comment: Steps to fix the issue given in this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/30204461/526438

Answer (score 0):

If my memory doesn't fail me, Spring 3.2.x does not support Java 8, you need upgrade to Spring 4

Comment: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11656 supported since 3.2.3 https://spring.io/blog/2013/05/21/spring-framework-4-0-m1-3-2-3-available

Comment: Thanks by the link Andreas. About your 3 Maven dependencies for **asm**, What happens if you only declare the first? What Java 8 update you are using?

Comment: Be sure to build again all your source code, of course now with Java 8.

Comment: +Andreas The SPR you link to says "fixed since 3.2.9", so presumably that was when support was considered "complete"

Answer (score 0):

Just try once to update asm jar with version **asm.5.0**