# Spring 3.x Application not working after updating from Java 7 to JAVA 8

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have an application that was running fine when using Java1.7. We have recently upgraded to JAVA 1.8 after which the application isn't working. Below is the exception I am getting while launching it

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class
: file [/gui/XXXXX$1.class];
 nested exception is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 13864
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:237)
```

We are using Spring 3.x with Java 8. Are they both compatible? If not to which version I have to upgrade? We cannot use JAVA 8 since other applications are built on that or is there a way to compile this source alone in JAVA 7? we are using maven to build the application. It is SEV1 priority so any help is highly appreciated. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Version 4.0 is the latest major release of the Spring Framework and the first to fully support Java 8 features.

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24657418/spring-core-3-2-9-java-8) stackoverflow item discussing the same issue.

Comment: So do you mean that spring 4 is required and 3.x is not compatible with java 8?

Comment: Yes, you need to upgrade.

Comment: Uograde to spring 4.x helped... Thanks