# Spring 3.2.x with Java 8

Tags: java, spring, java-8, version

We are currently using spring 3.2.9. We are thinking of upgrading that to a newer version. When I checked the documentation it says that

> Along with 4.0 M1, we’ve released Spring Framework 3.2.3, containing
>   fixes for recently reported issues but also coming with OpenJDK 8 runtime
>   support. Spring Framework 3.2.x will support deployment on JDK 8 runtimes
>   for applications compiled against JDK 7 (with -target 1.7) or earlier.

Does that imply that I can't compile on Java 8?
Should I use spring version 4.0.x if I wanna compile with Java 8?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a best effort support of JDK8 in the 3.2.x line, as of 3.2.9+.

See [SPR-11656](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11656) for initial support in 3.2.9 and [SPR-11979](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11979) for bytecode support improvements in 3.2.10. Please note the support limitations explained in the comments.

For comprehensive support of JDK8, please upgrade to Spring 4.x - there's a [dedicated wiki page explaining the upgrade path](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Migrating-from-earlier-versions-of-the-Spring-Framework), and the Spring team made great efforts to make that upgrade experience really easy.

Answer (score 5):

As per my observations, you can actually use spring 3 with code compiled in Java 8, **as long as you do not use new java8 syntax in there** (like lambdas) in the paths scanned.

So, you can use new APIs (streams ...), but not new syntax (lambdas...).

When I tried, I ended up with startup errors like *org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class*

Answer (score 3):

Versions of the Spring Framework that are older than 4.0M1 do not work with classes that are compiled for Java 8.

Spring tries to Proxy these classes by reading class files, which won't work if they're "too new". If your `@Service` classes are compiled with Java 8 as the target, Spring will fail to load the classes on startup.

This means that you will have to upgrade to Spring 4.x.x, if you want to target Java 8 (and use lambdas, default implementations and so on).

I encountered this problem myself a few months ago with a project that uses Spring 3.x.x.

Comment: I upvoted the answer. But I'm still trying to figure out whether is it possible to compile old spring app with java 8. e.g. booking-faces webapp

Comment: Hello, It's not true, Spring 3.2.X is compatible with java 8, it's just that you need version 3.2.9 minimum. I just updated an application that uses spring 3.2.3 and cannot works on Java 8 to spring 3.2.12 and with no other changes the application now works on java 8.