# Java 8 Spring compatibility

Tags: spring, java-8

I am currently migrating my application from Java 7 to Java 8 and currently I am running the Spring 3.1.6 jar. **Would this be compatible with Java 8 or I need to upgrade the Spring jar ?**

I understand that the Spring 4x version has natural support for Java 8, but this is time critical and I am seeking to change as little jars as I can.

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24657418/spring-core-3-2-9-java-8) could help you...

Comment: see this question and answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30072135/spring-3-2-x-with-java-8

Comment: Thank you, it helped me. So I have to bite the bullet and go for the Spring jar upgrade

Answer (score 26):

**Basically `Spring 3.x` versions supports up to `Java-7` only. If you want to migrate to `Java-8` you should use `Spring 4.x` version.**

> However some spring release notes says that the `Spring Framework 3.2.x`
>   will support deployment on `JDK 8` runtimes for applications compiled
>   against `JDK 7` (with -target 1.7) or earlier. Note that it won’t
>   support `JDK 8`’s bytecode format (-target 1.8, as needed for lambdas);
>   please upgrade to `Spring Framework 4.0` for that purpose.

Follow [this](http://spring.io/blog/2013/05/21/spring-framework-4-0-m1-3-2-3-available/) link to the source article.

Comment: Yes, that's it! If you compile on JDK 7 you can run on JRE 8 but you need 3.2.1.RELEASE version of Spring

Comment: I have migrated to JDK8 while using spring 3.2.9 with target runtime 1.8. I haven't faced any issues so far.

Answer (score 3):

No it is not compatible. I've run into the same issue and while many will say that Java 8 is completely backwards compatible with older versions of java, this turns out not to be true.

This has a very good explaination of the exact problem I ran into java 7 targeted code with java 8.

https://gist.github.com/AlainODea/1375759b8720a3f9f094

Because the API of ConcurrentHashMap has changed between the 2 java releases, spring breaks on startup and you end up with

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.keySet()Ljava/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap$KeySetView;
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.getInitParameterNames(ApplicationContext.java:368)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade.getInitParameterNames(ApplicationContextFacade.java:367)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.registerEnvironmentBeans(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.postProcessBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.java:163)
```

I had no choice to but upgrade to Spring 4.x (not sure if 3.2 or above would have worked as I jumped straight to 4.x)

Answer (score 3):

If some libraries (or the JRE itself) are JDK 8 and the component-scan feature of spring is enabled (and scans these libs/jdk classes), then the minimal spring version is 3.2.10-RELEASE.

The reason is the upgrade of ASM (the library that spring uses to scan compiled classes and detect annotations, implemented interfaces, etc.) in spring.

See [SPR-11979](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11979) and [SPR-11656](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11656) for details.

Comment: This worked great when I upgraded an old app from 3.2.2-RELEASE to 3.2.18.RELEASE

Answer (score -5):

Java 8 and the jvm 8 is completely backwards compatible with all older versions of java. Java takes painstaking steps to ensure new releases do not break old code. Any code you wrote for java 7 can be compiled with java 8, and any code you compiled for java 7 can run on jvm 8.