# Is Java 7 compatible with Spring version 3.2.8.RELEASE? Or which version of Java works with 3.2.8.RELEASE

Tags: spring, spring-3

We are using JDK 6 with Spring 3.2.8.RELEASE. Our application uses TLS, and the version of TLS needs to be upgraded to version 1.1 or higher. Unfortunately the JDK 6 (our build is 81) does not offer support for 1.1 or higher. So we are in need of upgrading JDK to 7. Question : Is Spring 3.2.8.RELEASE compatible to work with JDK 7?

Current code
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

I want to use

SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.1");

Would Spring version 3.2.8 RELEASE works good with Java 7 version? Or I need to upgrade Spring to 4.x release?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize for posting an earlier answer and pulling it.  It wasn't "wrong", but I wanted to find the definitive answer to your question.  That answer is, I believe, provided in the Spring 3.1 release notes:

https://spring.io/blog/2011/12/13/spring-framework-3-1-goes-ga/

The spring team announces here full compatibility with Java 7.  So you should be fine since you're one major point release ahead of that.

If you're thinking of jumping to Java 8, you should find this post helpful:

[Java 8 Spring compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32278878/java-8-spring-compatibility)