# Spring Ehcaching not working after Java 8 upgrade in Linux

Tags: spring, java-8, ehcache

We are using spring ehcache in our application, recently we upgraded the java version of the tomcat in which the app runs to 1.8.66.
Strangely there are no errors in the logs - but caching doesn't work on the linux machine.

On my local (windows) same version of java 1.8.66, it works like a charm... what could be the issue?

We are using aspecJ load time weaving with TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader - version 3.2.3.

Details of dependencies:

- ehcache 2.7.4
- aspectJ weaver 1.6.2
- spring 3.1.1

```
INFO  2015-12-28 14:09:19,667 (org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(EhCacheManagerFactoryBean.java:100)) - Initializing EHCache CacheManager
INFO  2015-12-28 14:09:19,828 (net.sf.ehcache.pool.sizeof.filter.AnnotationSizeOfFilter.<clinit>(AnnotationSizeOfFilter.java:53)) - Using regular expression provided through VM argument net.sf.ehcache.pool.sizeof.ignore.pattern for IgnoreSizeOf annotation : ^.*cache\..*IgnoreSizeOf$
INFO  2015-12-28 14:09:19,873 (net.sf.ehcache.pool.sizeof.JvmInformation.<clinit>(JvmInformation.java:446)) - Detected JVM data model settings of: 64-Bit HotSpot JVM with Compressed OOPs
INFO  2015-12-28 14:09:20,190 (net.sf.ehcache.pool.sizeof.AgentLoader.getAgentFile(AgentLoader.java:198)) - Extracted agent jar to temporary file /opt/projects/tomcat/instance_7/temp/ehcache-sizeof-agent7845091970407661363.jar
INFO  2015-12-28 14:09:20,190 (net.sf.ehcache.pool.sizeof.AgentLoader.loadAgent(AgentLoader.java:138)) - Trying to load agent @ /opt/projects/tomcat/instance_7/temp/ehcache-sizeof-agent7845091970407661363.jar
INFO  2015-12-28 14:09:20,199 (net.sf.ehcache.pool.impl.DefaultSizeOfEngine.<init>(DefaultSizeOfEngine.java:111)) - using Agent sizeof engine
INFO  2015-12-28 14:09:20,456 (net.sf.ehcache.pool.impl.DefaultSizeOfEngine.<init>(DefaultSizeOfEngine.java:111)) - using Agent sizeof engine
INFO  2015-12-28 14:09:20,746 (net.sf.ehcache.pool.impl.DefaultSizeOfEngine.<init>(DefaultSizeOfEngine.java:111)) - using Agent sizeof engine
INFO  2015-12-28 14:09:20,768 (net.sf.ehcache.pool.impl.DefaultSizeOfEngine.<init>(DefaultSizeOfEngine.java:111)) - using Agent sizeof engine
INFO  2015-12-28 14:09:20,789 (net.sf.ehcache.pool.impl.DefaultSizeOfEngine.<init>(DefaultSizeOfEngine.java:111)) - using Agent sizeof engine
```

I can see same logs in both Windows and Linux after application starts up
Could this be a issue with Linux JVM?

Comment: "caching does not work" is really vague. Can you be more specific on the differences observed between the different deployments?

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's a problem with spring 3.x.x and Java 8.
Take a look here [Spring 3.2.x with Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30072135/spring-3-2-x-with-java-8)