# Using Java 8 Features with Spring Framework: Compatibility with Spring 3.0.x and Beyond

Tags: spring, lambda, java-8, stream, compatibility

Given that Java 8 was released after Spring 3.0.x, is it possible to use Java 8 features such as Lambdas and Streams with Spring 3.0.x? If not, what is the earliest version of Spring that officially supports Java 8, and what are some of the Java 8 features that can be used with that version of Spring?

Comment: take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30072135/spring-3-2-x-with-java-8