# Getting "Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target" when running Maven integration testing

Tags: java-8, verifyerror, maven-failsafe-plugin, maven-compiler-plugin

I’m using Maven 3.2.3 with this version of Java

```
davea$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home
```

When I run

```
mvn clean install
```

I get errors like the below in my integration tests …

```
testFindSampleUsersByCodeAscByDefault(org.mainco.subco.user.service.SampleUserService2IT)  Time elapsed: 2.204 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 57
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/mainco/subco/user/service/SampleUserServiceImpl$ValueComparator.compare(Lorg/mainco/subco/user/domain/User;Lorg/mainco/subco/user/domain/User;)I @10: ifnull
  Reason:
    Expected stackmap frame at this location.
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2ab4 001b 2bb9 002e 0200 c600 2f2a b400
    0x0000010: 1b2b b900 2e02 00c0 0030 b600 34c6 001c
    0x0000020: 2ab4 001b 2bb9 002e 0200 c000 30b6 0034
    0x0000030: b600 39b6 003e a700 0512 404e 2ab4 001b
    0x0000040: 2cb9 002e 0200 c600 2f2a b400 1b2c b900
    0x0000050: 2e02 00c0 0030 b600 34c6 001c 2ab4 001b
    0x0000060: 2cb9 002e 0200 c000 30b6 0034 b600 39b6
    0x0000070: 003e a700 0512 403a 042d 1904 b600 4436
    0x0000080: 0515 0599 0016 2d19 04b6 0044 2d19 04b6
    0x0000090: 0044 b800 4a6c a700 0403 3606 1506 2ab4
    0x00000a0: 0023 9900 0702 a700 0404 a000 0502 ac04
    0x00000b0: ac                                     

    at org.mainco.subco.user.service.SampleUserServiceImpl.findSampleUsers(SampleUserServiceImpl.java:439)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy98.findSampleUsers(Unknown Source)
    at org.mainco.subco.user.service.SampleUserService2IT.testFindSampleUsersByCodeAscByDefault(SampleUserService2IT.java:215)
```

Here is how my compiler plugin is configured …

```
            <profile>
                    <id>jdk-8</id>
                    <activation>
                            <jdk>1.8</jdk>
                    </activation>
                    <build>
                            <plugins>
                                    <plugin>
                                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                                            <version>3.1</version>
                                            <configuration>
                                                    <source>1.8</source>
                                                    <target>1.8</target>
                                                    <compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>
                                                    <fork>true</fork>
                                            </configuration>
                                            <executions>
                                                    <execution>
                                                            <id>default-testCompile</id>
                                                            <phase>test-compile</phase>
                                                            <goals>
                                                                    <goal>testCompile</goal>
                                                            </goals>
                                                    </execution>
                                            </executions>
                                    </plugin>
                            </plugins>
                    </build>
            </profile>
```

and here is how my failsafe is configured

```
                    <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.18.1</version>
                            <configuration>
                                    <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                                    <argLine>-Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=512M -XX:-UseSplitVerifier ${itCoverageAgent}</argLine>
                                    <skipTests>${skipAllTests}</skipTests>
                            </configuration>
                            <executions>
                                    <execution>
                                            <goals>
                                                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                            </goals>
                                    </execution>
                            </executions>
                    </plugin>
```

Any ideas how to prevent these bizarre “Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target” errors I’m seeing?

**Edit:**

I'm using these dependnecies (as speculated by the comments that these were problems):

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.11.RELEASE:compile
...
[INFO] +- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.8.6:compile
```

Comment: Maven has nothing to do with you problem. There is a bytecode processing tool in your environment which is incompatible with recent bytecode features, whereas “recent” means “several years old”, but before Java 8, the `-XX:-UseSplitVerifier` option, you are using, helped ignoring these problems. First suspects are the AOP framework and the coverage agent. First attempt should be to update everything.

Comment: I removed the ${itCoverageAGent} option (didn't change anything) and am using Spring AOP 3.2.11.RELEASE and aspectj-weaver 1.8.6 (latest).  It is not an option to update Spring AOP.  Are you sayihng taht this version of Spring AOP is incompatible with Java 8?

Comment: I don’t know these libraries in detail. All I said, was that one of them must be the cause. A quick search revealed http://stackoverflow.com/a/27556298/2711488; maybe that helps.

Comment: I'm having trouble believing this is the cause.  When I run an individual test file, like "mvn clean test -Dtest=UserServiceIT", everything passes without errors.  Only when running "mvn clean install" when all the tests get run together do I see these VerifyErrors pop up.

Comment: Well, in order to reproduce it, the code must contain methods which AOP tries to instrument, and `StackMapFrame`s which this process can trash. This requires a sufficiently complex code, e.g. code without branches doesn’t have a `StackMapTable` attribute, thus no frames to trash. But if you have another bytecode manipulating library in your environment, which you suspect, you may check that. I did not claim to know for sure, who’s responsible, I’m only telling, what that error is about…

Comment: where did you set -noverify? I set it as MAVEN_OPTS but its not working for me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target JDK 1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15122890/java-lang-verifyerror-expecting-a-stackmap-frame-at-branch-target-jdk-1-7)

Answer (score 11):

I had this same problem when I moved to JDK 8.  Code built fine, just got these errors when running the unit tests.  I see you are using `-XX:-UseSplitVerifier`, which didn't work for me either.  I had found a short blurb somewhere that instead of using `-XX:-UseSplitVerifier` with JDK 8, I should use `-noverify`.  I gave it a try and it worked for me.

Hope this helps.

Comment: where did you set -noverify? I set it as MAVEN_OPTS but its not working for me

Answer (score 2):

before java8, you can add arg item of `-XX:-UseSplitVerifier` while starting jvm to solve such issue;

`UseSplitVerifier` arg item was removed by java8, but you can also use `-noverify` for replacement