# Java8 + Spring 3

Tags: java-8, spring-3

I'm aware that we can't use the advantages of java 8 with spring 3 such as `lambda expression`, `Optional`, `Stream`, etc ...

But how about the new way of handling memory ?

**Edit**

- By memory-handling i mean the new `metaspace` memory, `metaspace garbage collector`, the suppression of `permanent generation` ...
- Also, we couldn't upgrade `Spring` to latest version 4 because we had to upgrade `Hibernate` to 3.6 as well, and this is not possible for the moment (we are dealing with an old application).

Comment: Can you be specific about what memory-handling behavior you are referring to?

Comment: Spring 3 has had trouble in the past, due to byte code differences that broke dynamic proxying given what was available at the time. That began to be addressed in Spring 3.2.9 (see  https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11656).  Be sure there are no dependency conflicts that override Spring's dependencies with older versions.

Comment: @HankD see my edit

Comment: I think you are mixing things as Spring does not interfere with the garbage collection and the memory management. For the record we are successfully using the latest Spring 3.2 on Java 8.

Comment: @DidierL According to this  "Spring Framework 3.2.x will support deployment on JDK 8 runtimes for applications compiled against JDK 7 (with -target 1.7) or earlier. Note that it won’t support JDK 8’s bytecode format (-target 1.8, as needed for lambdas); please upgrade to Spring Framework 4.0 for that purpose. see https://spring.io/blog/2013/05/21/spring-framework-4-0-m1-3-2-3-available/ " You can't use lambda expression with Spring 3.2 on Java 8. How about the memory handling by java 8 ?

Comment: @Anarki those are just the release notes of version 3.2.3, you could use all the language features of Java 8 if you were using version 3.2.9 or more recent, as Hank said earlier. And as I said earlier, Spring does not affect the way memory management works in Java 8 – so metaspace will still be used (you could not remove it if you wanted to!). PermGen is gone.

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24657418/spring-core-3-2-9-java-8